# travis: Publish to npm on version bump

Tags: github, npm, travis-ci

I have a package already published to npm. TravisCI is used to automate some scripts.

Now i want to publish the latest version of my package to npm on a version bump.

Say my package is currently on version 1.1.0. I added some features, pushed those to Github, Travis tests those features using npm run test and builds successfully. Now when i bump my version to 1.2.0, i want Travis to read the change, test again, and now push the package to npm automatically with the latest version.

How do i do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck! TravisCI has [built-in support for releasing to npm](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/npm/) after a successful test run.

Comment: Thanks. But when i pushed a tag, travis went into an error "You must be login to publish the package". How to resolve the error ?

Comment: Do you have your [npm API key set up](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/npm/#NPM-auth-token) as an encrypted variable in your `.travis.yml` file?

Comment: Yes. I have setup the api key as suggested by travis.

Comment: Can you send us a link to the Travis CI logs and your source?